# Vim plugin for showing possible next keys?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

is there a vim setting or plugin to show the possible next keys (probably with comment)? I would like to have something like this for my `<leader>` mappings and it would be a huge benefit for beginners.

Workflow:

```
1. I type <leader>
2. Plugin pops up a sidebar with "gc - fugitive commit, gd - fugitive diff" etc
3. I can continue typing my command
```

Comment: if there was, it would be annoying plugin....

Answer (score 0):

I have the following, but this only works for groups of `<Leader>` mappings, e.g. the various `<Leader>c...` mappings from NERD_Commenter:

```
" <Leader>x     List all mappings defined in normal / visual mode that
" {Visual}<Leader>x start with <Leader>x (if any are defined and there is no
"           dedicated <Leader>x mapping itself).
function! s:MakeMappingHelperMappings()
    for l:i in range(65,90) + range(97,122)
        let l:char = nr2char(l:i)
        let l:map = '<Leader>' . l:char
        for l:mode in ['n', 'x']
            if ! empty(mapcheck(l:map, l:mode)) && empty(maparg(l:map, l:mode))
                execute printf('%snoremap %s :<C-u>%smap %s<CR>', l:mode, l:map, l:mode, l:map)
            endif
        endfor
    endfor
endfunction
call s:MakeMappingHelperMappings()
delfunction s:MakeMappingHelperMappings
```

This needs to be sourced *after* all plugins, so put this into `~/.vim/plugin/zzz_mapping_help.vim`, not `~/.vimrc`!

I don't see how something for `<Leader>` would be useful, that would give far too many options...